# Ruby of Rails shell environment variables error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, environment-variables

When I set the environment variables in the `.bash_profile` file and restart the `shell` I get the following error:

```
Last login: Sat Aug 15 20:16:25 on ttys000
-bash: /Users/xxxxxxxxx/.bash_profile: line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /Users/xxxxxxxx/.bash_profile: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

My `.bash_profile` file looks like this:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load       RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export GMAIL_USERNAME=“xxxxx@gmail.com”
export GMAIL_PASSWORD=“xxxxxx”
export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY=“xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”
export MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID=“xxxxxxxxxx”
export OWNER_EMAIL=“xxxxxx@gmail.com”
```

Comment: ricke2005, did you try my solution? That should fix your issue. Let me know if not!

Comment: KM, just tried your suggestion, ... IT WORKED! Thank you. I don't understand the difference is between the two symbols.  Can you explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to replace `”` with `"`like following:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load       RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export GMAIL_USERNAME="xxxxx@gmail.com"
export GMAIL_PASSWORD=“xxxxxx”
export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID="xxxxxxxxxx"
export OWNER_EMAIL="xxxxxx@gmail.com"
```